# PHP foreach database results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

CodeIgniter question: So I select data from db and I am printing the results like this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{       
   echo $row->db_item;
}
```

Foreach returns 3 rows and the result look like this:
    `010203`.

How do I make it so the result should be echoed like this (each row of the result to be sliced somehow, e.g. each row of the result to be retrieved separately):

```
01
02
03
```

One last thing, if I add another line after the foreach I only retrieve the last row of the result `03` and not the same `010203`. Why is that, theoretically?

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {       
       echo $row->db_item;
    }
    echo $row->db_item; //this returns 01020303
```

Comment: you're dumping to a web browser context, which means you have to use html means of providing line breaks, e.g. `<br>`

Answer (score 5):

Use an html line break

```
echo $row->db_item ."<br>";
```

or a newline character.

```
echo $row->db_item ."\n";
```

or both `"<br>\n"`

---

about the foreach loop:

```
echo $row->db_item; //this returns 01020303
```

that line actually prints out `03` but since you're not using line breaks, it just tacks `03` onto the end of the `010203` that was printed inside the foreach loop.

`$row` is still accessible and set to `03` because on the last iteration of the foreach loop, `$row` is set to the last element returned from `$query->result()`. If you would like to "clean it up", [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) it.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->db_item;
}
unset($row);
```

Comment: And after the `foreach` loop still pointing to the last key of the array, that's why shows you `03` :)

Comment: Thanks, but what if I would want to use one of the rows, let's say `02`?

Comment: You'd either cancel the foreach loop on `02` by using `break;` (you cant 'resume' the loop though) or set some outside variable to `02` on your way through the loop.

Comment: How would I go about setting a variable on each row, $first_row == $row[0], something like this?

Comment: `$query->result()` returns an array. Just do `$results = $query->result()`. and you'll have `$results[0]`, etc

Comment: I see, but when I use `$result[0]` it only returns the first character 0, not the whole row result as it should be, for example `02`.

Comment: My apologies, if you want it as an array, you'd use `$query->result_array()`